# I want to make a button swap two div wrappers and their children elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button change two divs and their children elements. Their children elements include an  and  with text. I just want to click the button and make the entire content swap places.

Here is the html and javascript.

```js
function switchTokens() {
  var obj1 = document.getElementById('from_token_select').value;
  var obj2 = document.getElementById('to_token_select').value;

  var temp = obj1;
  obj1 = obj2;
  obj2 = temp;

  // Save the swapped values to the input element.
  document.getElementById('from_token_select').value = obj1;
  document.getElementById('to_token_select').value = obj2;
}
```

```html
<div class="token_select" id="from_token_select">
  <img src="https://image-placeholder.com/images/actual-size/75x100.png" class="token_image" id="from_token_img" />
  <span id="from_token_text">from_token_text</span>
</div>

<button onClick="switchTokens()" id="swap_token_address" class="fa-solid fa-arrows-up-down">switchTokens Btn</button>

<div class="token_select" id="to_token_select">
  <img src=https://image-placeholder.com/images/actual-size/88x31.png class="token_image" id="to_token_img" />
  <span id="to_token_text">to_token_text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the class?

Comment: use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Comment: If you wrap these elements in a flex or grid container you could use the CSS [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property on the parent to reverse their rendered positions without changing any markup.

Comment: Thank you all, and yes, I also want to swap the classes as when I refer to swapping everything is every single element contained in the divs.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you'd like to swap the entire contents of the divs? If that's the case, this JS does the trick:

```
function switchTokens() {
  var obj1 = document.getElementById('from_token_select').innerHTML;
  var obj2 = document.getElementById('to_token_select').innerHTML;

  
  // Save the swapped values to the input element.
  document.getElementById('from_token_select').innerHTML = obj2;
  document.getElementById('to_token_select').innerHTML = obj1;
}
```